# How to restrict google autocomplete results to city, state, country, zip only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using **react-places-autocomplete** package. currently i have restricted to region and US.

Now i am trying to restrict to city, state, country and zip only.

**Problem:**

> 1. If i use regions it is showing towns also but i need **only city, state, country and zip** in search
> 2. If i use cities it is showing **city, state and country but zip is not showing in search.**

**Expected Output**
i want output like city, state, country and zip exculding locality, towns, subloclity

**Code**

```
import PlacesAutocomplete, {
    geocodeByAddress,
    getLatLng,
  } from 'react-places-autocomplete';

const searchOptions = {
    types: ['(regions)'],
    // types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
}

 handleChange = address => {
    this.setState({ address });
  };

  handleSelect = address => {
    geocodeByAddress(address)
      .then(results => getLatLng(results[0]))
      .then(latLng => console.log('Success', latLng))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error', error));
  };

render() {
    const renderFunc = ({ getInputProps, suggestions, getSuggestionItemProps, loading }) => (
            <div>
                <input
                    className="location-field"
                    {...getInputProps({
                        placeholder: 'Search Places ...',
                        className: 'input-box location-search-input form-control field-list',
                    })}
                />
                <div className="autocomplete-dropdown-container">
                    {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
                    {suggestions.map(suggestion => {
                        const className = suggestion.active
                            ? 'suggestion-item--active'
                            : 'suggestion-item';
                        // inline style for demonstration purpose
                        const style = suggestion.active
                            ? { backgroundColor: '#fafafa', cursor: 'pointer', margin: '0px 0px 0px 10px', width: '70%' }
                            : { backgroundColor: '#ffffff', cursor: 'pointer', margin: '0px 0px 0px 10px', width: '70%'};
                        return (
                            <div
                                {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestion, {
                                    className,
                                    style,
                                })}
                            >
                                <span>{suggestion.description}</span>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        );

    retrun <div>
        <PlacesAutocomplete
        value={this.state.address}
        onChange={(address)=>this.handleChange(address)}
        onSelect={(e)=>this.handleSelect(e, fieldConstants.region)}
        searchOptions={searchOptions}
        >
            {renderFunc}
        </PlacesAutocomplete>

    </div>
}
```

Comment: Just read the official Google docs about the `types` parameter. You can't combine them except for `geocode` and `establishment` but that's the same as specifying no types. Any example where Autocomplete returns a **ZIP code**?

Comment: @MrUpsidown if we use type as region then it will return zip code as well as locality, sublicality, state, country. so here i want to restrict to only zip, state, county, and city

Comment: Please edit your question to include an example query and results, and an example of what you expect.